# Having trouble with the encryption key for PEPK tool

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-signing

**I am trying to sing in my existing apps on play console. I have to generate an app signing key and for that play console provides me a PEPK.jar file. Now there is four parameter (keystore,alias,output,encryptionkey) to run the command and generate an app signing key file. I do understand the first 3 parameters (keystore, alias, output) but I am having trouble with the 4th parameter which is "encryptionkey".So suggestion needed that what would be the possible encryption key?**

> $ java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=foo --output=encrypted_private_key_path --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a

Answer (score 4):

[From the help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423):

> PEPK tool: Play Encrypt Private Key is a tool for exporting private keys from a Java Keystore and encrypting private keys for transfer to Google Play.

The instructions are also in the [help center article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) above, in the section "Existing apps".

The final argument **encryptionKey** is the Google Play store public key. It is used to encrypt your key so it can be transfered securely to Google, and only they can decrypt it. The Play console should display you exactly the command line to run (including the key) when you follow the steps in the help doc:

> - Find your original app signing key.
> - Sign in to your Play Console.
> - Select an app.
> - On the left menu, click Release management > App signing.
> - **Follow the on-screen instructions** to transfer your original app signing key.
>
>   - Optional: You can also generate an upload key and register it with Google.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Nick, the encryption key is not to be modified, just copy-paste the one Google Play gives you in the command-line.